# Servlets encodeRedirectURL

Tags: java, session, servlets, oauth

I'm trying to get an OAuth implementation running on a servlet for Twitter.  I'm having trouble with redirecting the user to the Twitter authentication page.  When I get the callback, it's returned to a servlet but the session is different since the request comes from Twitter and not my webapp.

I tried using encodeRedirectURL to get the session to persist to the outside site but that doesn't work.  Need help!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the session ID as `jsessionid` fragment of callback URL. Twitter has to callback to http://example.com/callbackservlet;jsessionid=1E6FEC0D14D044541DD84D2D013D29ED (note: the jsessionid value is here just an example).

The [`HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) (and `encodeURL()`) won't encode the URL when the client already supports cookies. You need to hard-encode it yourself.

```
String url = "http://example.com/callbackservlet";
String encodedURL = url + ";jsessionid=" + request.getSession().getId();
```

Comment: Good answer! But I ran into another problem with it.  The callback returns to request parameters but Tomcat strips everything from jsessionid to the end of the URL off so I lose those parameters.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Tomcat who is doing that? Isn't there some `Filter` in your webapp which is doing like `response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI())` based on some condition?